# ServiceStack DateTime Handling

Tags: servicestack

I am having a problem with the DateTime format that is being utilized by ServiceStack.

For example I have a simple request object like this.

```
public class GetAllUpdatedStudents : IReturn<GetAllUpdatedStudentsResponse>
{
    public DateTime LastUpdate { get; set; }
}
```

When submitting a DateTime(mm/dd/yyyy) of 12/10/2016, ServiceStack converts it to a DateTime format of (dd/mm/yyyy), so the system thinks it is October 12th instead of December 10th.

How do I tell ServiceStack to not do this and us the format of mm/dd/yyyy when binding DateTime properties to request objects?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The most appropriate and least ambiguous way to send DateTime's over the wire is to always use the [ISO 8601 Date Format](https://xkcd.com/1179/). ServiceStack supports multiple date formats with numerous variations of IS0 8601 but there's no configuration in ServiceStack that supports formats with month before the date like `mm/dd/yyyy` which is interpreted as `dd/mm/yyyy`. But to avoid any ambiguity you should ideally be sending `YYYY-MM-DD` formats.

If you need to accept `MM/DD/YYYY` you can change it to a string, e.g:

```
public class GetAllUpdatedStudents : IReturn<GetAllUpdatedStudentsResponse>
{
    public string LastUpdate { get; set; }
}
```

Then parse it using your preferred DateTime format within your Service implementation.

You could override the built-in DateTime serialization to parse it in your specific Date Format with something like:

```
JsConfig.DeSerializeFn = str => {
    return DateTime.ParseExact(str,"MM/dd/yyyy",null);
};
```

But I'd recommend against doing this as your Services would not be as interoperable.

Comment: Excellent. I actually did almost the same thing.  I changed all my DateTime properties to String. Then using the validation plugin, I verified that the string being passed in followed YYYY-MM-DD format. Then next step is to validate that the date is actually a valid date.

I must say that ServiceStack has made programming fun again!

Thanks.